# Remove DOM-Element with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to remove a navbar based on the current location path.

This is what I have so far:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .controller('MainController', function ($location, $document) {
    if ($location.path().indexOf('resetpass') > -1) {
      var navbar = angular.element($document.querySelector(".top-navbar"));
      navbar.remove();
    }
  });
```

With this approach the console says:

```
angular.js:14110 TypeError: $document.querySelector is not a function
at new <anonymous> (main.controller.js:6)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4762)
at $controllerInit (angular.js:10518)
at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9416)
at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8757)
at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8760)
at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8637)
at angular.js:1808
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17913)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18013)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `ngIf` in your `DOM` element and do something like this:

Template :

```
<element ng-if="hideElemet"></element>
```

Controller :

```
if ($location.path().indexOf('resetpass') > -1) {
      $scope.hideElement = false
}
```

ngIf will remove the element from the DOM

Answer (score 3):

Try with `document`, not `$document`.

```
var navbar = angular.element(document.querySelector(".top-navbar")).remove();
```

Comment: ..the console error is gone, but the navbar is still visible.

Comment: still visible after you execute `navbar.remove();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like Ze Rubeus way of hiding the navbar makes more sense, but if you want to continue with what you have this should work:

```
angular.module('myModule')
 .controller('MainController', function ($location, $document) {
   if ($location.path().indexOf('resetpass') > -1) {
     var navbar = angular.element($document[0].querySelector(".top-navbar"));
     navbar[0].remove();
   }
});
```

Angular wraps all of it's DOM elements, so to access the element directly you need to grab the first element.

Comment: ..don't know why, but it won't work. I go with the approach of Ze Rubeus..